# Submitting Struts2 iterator index as a map key not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am running into an interesting problem and I can't really figure out what it is.

I have a a struts iterator that display a textfield. Defined like so:

```
    <s:form action="AddSubmit" method="post" theme="simple">
        <s:iterator status="rowStatus" value="otherList">
                <div>
                   <span>Input Value:</span>
                   <s:textfield theme="simple" 
                        name="valueMap[%{#rowStatus.index} + '-custom'].inputValue"/>
                                    </div>
        </s:iterator>
        <s:submit value="Save" theme="simple" />
   </s:form>
```

When I submit, the iterator value `%{#rowStatus.index}` does not evaluate to anything and the value is never set, but when I hardcode a key like `0`, it works. Any idea on what is going on?

Comment: Anything else is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
name="%{'valueMap[\\'' + #rowStatus.index + '-custom\\'].inputValue'}"
```

`%{ OGNL expression }` is used to force OGNL evaluation of an attribute that would normally be interpreted as a String literal.

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: @Seephor, what about `name="%{'valueMap[\\'' + #rowStatus.index + '-custom\\'].inputValue'}"`

Comment: hey that worked! ok... so why does it need to be wrapped like that?

Comment: surprisingly it doesn't work if I have the '-' before custom, but it does without. Does it need to be escaped or something? I tried '\\-custom\\' but no luck.

Comment: @Seephor, It's surprising, could you please try `_` (underline) instead.